# Cómo convierto contenido a propiedades en Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Con load() me estoy trayendo datos de otros sitio

```
<div class="contenedor">red</div>
```

Y en la actual hoja, tengo:

```
<div class="otro-contenedor"></div>
```

Estoy tratando de asignar el contenido de contenedor, en este caso "red", como propiedad css al otro contenedor:

```
var propiedad = $(".contenedor").text();
$(this).find('.otro-contenedor').css('background', propiedad)
```

Pero cuando me lo devuelve, lo hace como indefinido o null.

¿Alguna ayuda? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicación mas abajo.
He visto que tienes un error en:

```
$(this).find('.otro-contenedor').css('background', propiedad)
```

Lo cambié por:

```
$('.otro-contenedor').css("background",propiedad)
```

De esta manera haces referencia directamente al div en cuestión.

El atributo this hace referencia al elemento referenciado en una función. Como en este caso de ejemplo con la clase "padre-contenedor", como puede ser:

```
<div class="contenedor">red</div>
<div class="padre-contenedor" style="padding:20px;">
    <div class="otro-contenedor" style="padding:20px;"></div>
</div>
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

    $('.padre-contenedor').on('click', function() {

        let propiedad = $(".contenedor").text()

        $(this).find('.otro-contenedor').css("background",propiedad)
    })

});
</script>
```

Al hacer click en el elemento div "padre-contenedor" coge el texto del elemento div "contenedor" y en el div con la clase "padre-contenedor" busca un elemento hijo con la clase "otro-contenedor" y le añade la propiedad CSS background: "red" en este caso.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes localizar el segundo contenedor por el nombre de la clase, no es necesario el find.

```js
var propiedad = $(".contenedor").text();
console.log(propiedad);
$('.otro-contenedor').css('background', propiedad)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">red</div>

<div class="otro-contenedor">Este es el contenido de otro-contenedor</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El `this` en el contexto global hace referencia al objeto global `window` es lo que ocurre en tu caso. Por eso el `find` te devuelve `undefined`.

Deberías buscar en `body`.

```js
var propiedad = $(".contenedor").text();
$('body').find('.otro-contenedor').css('background', propiedad)
```

```css
.otro-contenedor {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">red</div>
<div class="otro-contenedor"></div>
```

He añadido `css` para que pudieras ver que se aplican los estilos.